# Change fontSize based on value

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my code:

```
$("#fontSize").keyup(function() {
    var change = $("#fontSize").val();
    $("#x").text(change + " font size");
})
```

The above works fine, but I would also like to change the CSS `fontSize` with the value from `#fontSize`.

I've tried to add `$( "#x" ).style.fontSize( change );` but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Use `$('#x').css('font-size', change + 'px');`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that earlier, i also try $( "#rText1" ).css({ fontSize: "50px", color: "red" }); just to try to change it at all but it doesn't work :/

Comment: is #fontSize a text input? What element is #x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

To change a property, the first argument is the name. `font-size` or `fontSize`.
The second argument is the value. ex: `16px`

```
$('#x').css('font-size', change + 'px');
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [the jQuery .css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) (it will be your best friend in dynamic styling). Your code could be modified as follows:

```
$("#fontSize").keyup(function() {
    var change = $("#fontSize").val();
    $("#x").text(change + " font size");

    // This will set X's font size to change in PIXELS
    $("#x").css('fontSize', change + 'px');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just chain the jQuery `css()` method for `font-size` to your jQuery `text()` method:

```
$("#fontSize").keyup(function() {
    var change = $("#fontSize").val();
    $("#x").text(change + " font size").css(fontSize, change + "px");
});
```

I am using `fontSize` instead of `"font-size"` since i am not using quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$('#x').css("font-size", change + "px");
```

right after putting text